# Session Cookie HTTPOnly flag not set on response from logout (Django)

Tags: python, django, security, httponly

I have a Django application and am configuring some security settings. One of the settings is the `SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` flag. I set this flag to True.

On session creation (login) I can see the session `HTTPOnly` flag set if I inspect cookies. On logout, the server sends back a session cookie update with an empty value to show that the cookie has been destroyed. This empty cookie is not sent back with the `httpOnly` flag set.

My question: Is this a security concern? Is there a way to force Django to set this flag on logout? Or is this just expected behavior, and is not a security concern, since the session cookie that is returned is blank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On logout, the server sends back a session cookie update with **an empty
>   value** to show that the cookie has been destroyed.

The `HTTPOnly` flag is set to prevent an XSS vulnerability from disclosing the secret session ID. When the cookie is "deleted" by setting it to an empty value, any sensitive data is removed from the cookie. An attacker doesn't have any use for an empty value, so it is not necessary to set the `HTTPOnly` flag.

On top of that, the expire date is set in the past, and the `max-age` is set to `0`. The client will delete the cookie immediately, leaving any attacker with no chance to read the cookie through an XSS attack.

Comment: Cool. I figured this was the case. Thanks for confirming!